# Oracle Apex dynamic action not firing on true condition

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a page with two Interactive Grids. One shows Approved records. One shows Unapproved records. There is a button with processing underneath on each grid to set the selected rows to Approved/Unapproved respectively.

I want to hide these buttons based on if a user is an Approver. These values are store in some user managed tables.

I have a dynamic action on Page Load that runs the following and sets a page item to 1 / null depending on the return:

```
select 1 from users where upper(username) = upper(:APP_USER) and userrole = 'APPROVER';
```

Based on the value in the page item two dynamic actions fire on page load to set the buttons with

- True=Show
- False=Hide.
- Client Side Condition: Item = Value: P1_PAGE_ITEM = 1

Now - on my local machine this works fine. I made the page item visible. Can see a 1 or null and the buttons are hidden/shown.

I moved this to a Development environment and now I get a warning about Unsaved Changes each time I click out of the page (doesn't happen on Local). And although I can see a 1 in the Page Item field the actions see this as False (I put an alert on to fire when true/false).

Question is: Why am I getting the unsaved changes warning on the new environment. And why would the actions see the field as FAlse.

I have compared all of the properties as best as I can and they seem identical. I have even arranged the sequence numbers to be identical in the two environments.

All thoughts welcome...

Comment: You seem to have several questions here. Let's start with this one: "I moved this to a Development environment and now I get a warning about Unsaved Changes each time I click out of the page." Create a new page with an IG. Do you get this behavior there? If no, then it's something on the page in question (not some global JS). Next, create a new IG region on the page in question. Do you get this behavior there? If no, then it's something related to the region on the page (likely JS config). Try experimenting like this to help isolate the issue.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't need to be a DA that is modifying a field value, hence the alert.

Why not define a computation that executes during the render, and use that as a server side condition on your Dynamic Action?

Otherwise you've enabled a security threat, where the user can tweak some HTML to see the regions you've hidden.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that. I would like to know why one environment behaves differently to another - starting with the alert an then why the DA doesn't see the condition is True. Is there a way to bottom that out?

Comment: Different environment - likely data issue? Run page in debug mode, check browser console for DA behaviour.